# JavaFX scene builder fx-background-image doesnt show up

Tags: javafx

I´ve tried everything but it simply doesn't show up.
This is what my CSS file looks like:

```css
.fundo{
    -fx-background-image: url("../Resources/image.png");
    -fx-height: 500px;
    -fx-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -fx-background-position: center;
}
```

This is what my JavaFX screen setup + CSS looks like:

[image: screenshot - scene builder]

The idea was to add a border, like in the below image, but covering the entire bottom of the screen:

[image: with border]

I am an absolute JavaFX beginner and will be so thankful for your help.
(Sorry for bad English, I'm Brazilian.)

I've tried CSS, native JavaFX scene builder properties, nothing showed up. Only way I managed to show the image was by `ImageView` but then it doesn't resize and breaks my responsive design.

Comment: Update the question add: 1. Your file tree structure. 2. "image.png". 3. Your FXML file as text, formatted as code. 4. Java test application (as text formatted as code) you use to display the app (just load the fxml and CSS and show it, you don't need the controller code or any other code). 5. Build tool used (e.g. Maven or Gradle).

Comment: Study: [Where to put resource files in JavaFX](https://edencoding.com/where-to-put-resource-files-in-javafx/).  It discusses: ["loading a resource in CSS"](https://edencoding.com/where-to-put-resource-files-in-javafx/#loading-a-resource-in-css) and (if you need it) loading a resource, e.g. a stylesheet, in fxml.